# Javascript regex for money with max length

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I want validate a money string with numbers max length 13 with 2 decimal. I have a comma as decimal separator and a period as a thousands separator.

I have this regex:

```
/^(\d{1}\.)?(\d+\.?)+(,\d{2})?$/
```

For sintax is valid but not for max length. What I need to add to this regex?

For example, these strings must be valid:

```
1.000.000.000.000
1.000.000.000.000,00
1
1,00
123,45
```

And these must be invalid:

```
10.000.000.000.000
10.000.000.000.000,00
10.000.000.000.000.000
10.000.000.000.000.000,00
```

Comment: If you need to make sure there should be less than 16 digits in the string, add `(?!(?:\D*\d){16})` after `^`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for your answer, is valid, but is a little more complex than other answers.

Comment: I do not think `(?=[\d.]{1,17}(?:,\d{2})?$)` is "less complex" than `(?!(?:\D*\d){16})`, but feel free to use any solution that works for you best. ``(?!(?:\D*\d){16})`` syntax is universal to ignore the count of any non-digits. `(?![\d.]{18})` follows a similar logic (though it has to rely on the subsequent consuming pattern to work correctly), but is more specific since it only matches dots as non-digits.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not an expert with regex and I can't try your solution in regex101 or similar page. But I understand your solution, can't try that is the little complex. Thanks you very much for your time. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for validation:

```sh
^(?=[\d.]{1,17}(?:,\d{2})?$)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n8RyvY/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=[\d.]{1,17}(?:,\d{2})?$)`: Lookahead to match dot or digit 1 to 17 times followed by optional comma and 2 digits
- `\d{1,3}`: Match 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{3})*`: Match `.` followed by 3 digits. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `(?:,\d{2})?`: Match optional `,` followed 2 decimal digits
- `$`: End

Comment: Thanks anubhava for your answer, is that I need. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try to assert position is not followed by 18 digits/dots using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?![\d.]{18})\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d\d?)?$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0rqol/1). Here is assumed you would also allow a single digit decimal.

- `^` - Open line anchor.
- `(?![\d.]{18})` - Negative lookahead to prevent 18 digits/dots ahead.
- `\d{1,3}` - One-to-three digits.
- `(?:\.\d{3})*` - A non-capture group of a literal dot followed by three digits with a 0+ multiplier.
- `(?:,\d\d?)?` - Optional non-capture group of a comma followed by either 1 or two digits. Remove the question mark to make the 2nd decimal non-optional.
- `$` - End line anchor.

Comment: @Corporativo. You are welcome. Feel free to accept an answer that worked for you to close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

90% of the time there is a better solution than using regex. It's probably best just to convert your strings into a real number then compare vs. your limit (ie `9999999999999.99`).

```js
// Pass a string
function convertStr(string) {
  /*
  Remove all '.'
  Replace all ',' with '.'
  */
  let numStr = string.split('.').join('').replaceAll(',', '.');
  // Convert modified string into a real number
  let realNum = parseFloat(numStr);
  /*
  if converted string is a real number...
  round it to two decimal places and return it
  Otherwise return false
  */
  return !Number.isNaN(realNum) ? Math.round((realNum + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 : false;
}

// Pass a string and the maxed number 
function numLimit(string, limit) {
  // Get the result of convertString()
  let number = convertStr(string);
  // if the result is equal to or less than limit...
  if (number <= limit) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const limit = 9999999999999.99;
const valid = ['1.000.000.000.000',
  '1.000.000.000.000,00', '1', '1,00', '123,45'
];
const invalid = ['10.000.000.000.000', '10.000.000.000.000,00', '10.000.000.000.000.000', '10.000.000.000.000.000,00'];

let validResults = valid.map(str => numLimit(str, limit));

let invalidResults = invalid.map(str => numLimit(str, limit));

console.log('valid: ' + validResults);
console.log('invalid: ' + invalidResults);
```

Comment: Thanks zer00ne for work an alternative solution for regex, looks fine, but, if regex works fine in one line, why make this solution? Regards.

Comment: Try adapting that one line when input parameters are even slightly different. I could streamline it but then novices such as yourself wouldn't understand so easily.